# SharePoint Bug? Conflict Error when saving a Page with a "Required" DateTime field in the page layout

Tags: page-layout, column, publishing-page, date-time, save

I've just recently encountered a weird error / bug in SharePoint. Here is the scenario:

- I have a custom column "Test Date" that is of DateTime field type. The field is configured as required.
- It is added to a custom Content Type "Test CT" that is based on a "Publishing Page" content type
- I have created a Page Layout "Test PL" which is based on that particular content type.

Now here is what happens:

1. I try to create a page based on both that Content Type and Page Layout in the Pages Library. I manage to create it successfully.
2. However, when I go to try and edit the page, fill-in the required values and try to save it using the PAGE tab -> Save button, I get the below error/s. Note that this happens no matter what I choose in the drop-down menu for Save Button.

> The file XXX has been modified by user on date

But I know I am the ONLY user modifying the page.

*If I try to save again it gives me options to whether Discard my Changes, Keep Editing, Overwrite Changes, or Merge.*

- However, if I use the Save button on the upper right corner of the screen (the shortcut). I am able to save successfully without any errors!

The only thing I've tried that made it work was if I made the DateTime optional. But I need it to be required.

Is there any workaround to this error / bug?

Comment: I've had a similar problem which I'm hoping to resolve soon. If I manage it I will post up what I did.

Comment: I've just spent hours investigating the very same behavior. We recently installed the October CU, and got the error thereafter. Which version of SharePoint are you running? However, we also deployed a lot of custom changes as well, so It's difficult to trace the source of the problem. Do you have any custom event receivers? If you do, make sure you don't update the fields in the ItemUpdating event. And @Steve, If you resolved this, please post your answer. :)

Comment: Hi Johannes, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

We weren't using Event Receivers and the save conflict only occurred for the button in the Ribbon, whereas the additional Save button on the right of the ribbon (near the "focus" button) did not cause the issue.  I later posted a question on the Microsoft Partner forums and was pleased to eventually receive confirmation that it was an issue with the Microsoft code, and not something we had introduced.

The down side of this is that it isn't resolved for our clients.  There are a couple of work-arounds - one is to use the button on the right of the ribbon to save (not ideal), another is to bypass Save and simply Check-in or Publish a page directly, both of which work okay but again they aren't "solutions" to the problem, merely a way for authors to work-around the problem.

It looks like we'll have to wait to see how or if this gets addressed in future service packs.